# AngularJS $http.delete and $http.put don't work in real life

Tags: angularjs, http-delete, http-put

I have made a simple CRUD application with AngularJS which retrieves the data with a simple RESTful API (https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api).
Testing on localhost gives no error at all. All working as expected.
Testing on a remote server: only the Create ($http.post) and Read ($http.get) operations work well. 
The Update ($http.put) and Delete operations ($http.delete) however fail with a 403 error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).
Anyone any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: Can you specify the web server software you run on the remote server? Is it IIS? Or Apache? Or Nginx? I can probably help you allow those HTTP verbs.

Comment: Web server is running Apache. Unfortunately I don't have admin access to this server. I already contacted the administrator. For security reasons he won't allow PUT and DELETE requests.